# Can't get list of issues with multiple instances of the same parameter

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, bitbucket

I'm trying to get list of issues from Bit Bucket via REST API with OAuth.js (http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/). I'm signing every request with

```
OAuth.completeRequest(message, accessor);
```

where message is

```
message: {
  action: "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/owner/reponame/issues",
  method: "GET",
  parameters: p;
};
```

When **p** contains parameters with different names, everything is OK:

```
p = [['status','open'],['priority','high']]
```

but when **p** contains parameters with the same name

```
p = [['status','open'],['status','resolved']]
```

, server responds **401 UNAUTHORIZED**.
Bitbucket API support mutliple instances of the same parameter:

> You can query for multiple instances of the same parameter. The system treats multiple instances of the same parameter as an OR for the overall filter query. For example, the following filter looks for open and resolved bugs with the word for in the title:

```
status=open&kind=!bug&status=resolved&title=~for
```

I think that problem somewhere in signing methods of the OAuth.js library, but can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug on bitbucket side:
https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7009/you-cannot-use-multiple-identical-query